# How to bind property name of the data model object in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a data model class and have another created a property of another class type inside that.
Ex:

```cs
public class Properties
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public TypeExt Property { get; set; }        
}

public class TypeExt
{
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string DataTypeExt { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when i bind the values, everything works fine except that i need the PropertyName value to come as the Label for Property so that the final Json becomes like this.

```
{
   "Properties":[
      {
         "Test1Property":{
            "DataType":"Unsigned integer ",
            "DataTypeExt":"64bit",
            "Type":"PM"
         }
      },
      {
         "Test2Propert":{
            "DataType":"Integer ",
            "DataTypeExt":"64bit",
            "Type":"PM"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Hema - I assume your referring that the `Test1Property` in the JSON is the actual value of `Properties.PropertyName`?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I am referring to Properties.PropertyName. Can i get the binding like this by making change in model class or may be if there is any other way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get it so you get the `PropertyName` to be a key is by using a `Dictionary` as part of your model.

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, TypeExt>();

var test1Property = new TypeExt { Type = "PM", DataType = "Integer", DataTypeExt = "64bit" };
var test2Property = new TypeExt { Type = "PM", DataType = "Unsigned Integer", DataTypeExt = "64bit" };

properties.Add("Test1Property", test1Property);
properties.Add("Test2Property", test2Property);
```

What this results in when serialized is the following. It is a slightly different JSON than what you have above though. Notice that it is no longer an "array-of-objects", but an object that contains properties, each of which are the dictionary keys.

```
{
  "Test1Property" : { 
    "Type": "PM",
    "DataType": "Integer",
    "DataTypeExt": "64bit"
  },
  "Test2Property" : {
    "Type": "PM",
    "DataType": "Unsigned Integer",
    "DataTypeExt": "64bit"
  }
}
```